# A sequence of real numbers

Tags: mathematics

A sequence of real numbers is such that the the sum of every $5$ consecutive terms is $+ve$ while the sum of every $9$ consecutive terms is $-ve$. Then the sequence can have **at most** $n$ terms.

What is the value of $n$ $?$

Comment: Every 5 consecutive terms and every 9 consecutive terms of the infinite sequence {0,0,0,...} sum to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> 12

Explanation:

> General formula for this [IMO 1977 problem](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln772.html) has been derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723719/a-generalization-of-imo-1977-problem-2) on Math.SE  
>  $p\to$`Number of consecutive terms giving +ve sum`
> $q\to$`Number of consecutive terms giving -ve sum` 
>  $$n=p+q-2$$

Answer (score 1):

Further to prog_SAHIL's answer, one example is

> 4, 3, 4, -16, 6, 4, 4, 6, -16, 4, 3, 4

where the respective sums of 5 consecutive terms are

> 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1

and the respective sums of 9 consecutive terms are

> -1, -1, -1, -1